# Using boolean constant to check whether a parameter is defined

Tags: typescript

Using Typescript 2.8.3, I don't understand why the following code fails to get that params is defined inside the if block.

```
const testFunction = (params?: string) => {
  const paramIsDefined = typeof params !== 'undefined';
  if (paramIsDefined) {
    console.log(params.length);
  }
};
```

I get this error:
    TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined' on the console.log line for the params variable.

Whereas this code works:

```
const testFunction = (params?: string) => {
  if (typeof params !== 'undefined') {
    console.log(params.length);
  }
};
```

What am I not understanding / doing wrong ?

Comment: As far as I'm aware type guards *only* work directly in the conditional: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The construct:

```
if (typeof params !== 'undefined') {
    console.log(params.length);
}
```

is a type guard, and so will impact the type of `params`.

`if (paramIsDefined)` is just an `if` statement, it is true that the boolean value that is checked comes from a type check, but the compiler simply does not follow this. If you want to narrow the type of `params` form `string|undefined` to just `string` you need to use the type guard construct or use an assertion

Comment: ok, thx for the answer, works as it supposed to then.  
From a new typescript user perspective it feels very counter intuitive though...

Comment: @Nihau yeah I agree it feels counter intuitive but typescript can't track everything unfortunately